# intel NUC + Ubuntu 16.04 or 17.04 + vnc = wow, so slow!

Tags: hdmi, vnc

I bought a NUC 7i5bnk awhile back to use as a headless server.  The plan is to use SSH primarily, with VNC there as a sort of access backup to SSH.  In both 16.04 and 17.04, VNC frame rates are abysmal when no monitor is attached. Logging on from the desktop takes about a minute.  Merely hovering over an icon to bring up the tooltip takes about 8-10 seconds before the animation completes.  Its effectively unusable.

But if I connect a monitor to the NUCs HDMI port, then vavoom, everything is smooth and speedy.

I've seen a couple other similar threads with with one of two answers; fixes include either a dummy plug or some sort of null video driver from x.org.  Those threads are older, and I am wondering if there isn't just some kind of boot or video initialization setting that would do it.  I'm relatively new to linux but this seems like something that should be handled in the OS without hardware hacks or imposter drivers.

Comment: When the computer is connected to a monitor (or two) it queries the monitor for size, resolution etc. Without a monitor it has no way to know how big the display should be. The fake driver does just that.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  This [dummy plug](https://rumorscity.com/2013/12/06/how-to-create-dummy-plugs-for-your-graphics-cards/) did the job.

Comment: @jayray Can you please describe how did you resolved the issue. I have the same setup at remote site and facing slow vnc connection issue. Thanks